# How Can I Iterate Through A Node List And Replace The Content If Certain Conditions Are Met?

Tags: java, xml, dom

I try to iterate through the .xml file you can see below and check for every user (here: user1 and user2), if the value of the current-tag is the same as the value of the total-tag and if not, add a certain value (+10 for example) to the value of the current-tag.

```
<config>
    <users>
        <user1>
            <name>test1</name>
            <stats>
                <total>50</total>
                <current>50</current>
            </stats>
        </user1>
        <user2>
            <name>test2</name>
            <stats>
                <total>50</total>
                <current>20</current>
            </stats>
        </user2>
    </users>
</config>
```

I use the following code for iterating through the child nodes of the `stats`-tag and comparing for every user the value of the `current`-tag with the value of the `total`-tag:

```
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder;
        docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(names_saves);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList stats = doc.getElementsByTagName("stats");

        for(int i = 0; i < stats.getLength(); i++) {
            org.w3c.dom.Node n = stats.item(i);
            NodeList children= n.getChildNodes();
            for ( int x = 0; x < children.getLength(); x++ ) {
                Node elem = children.item(x);

                int current = 0;
                int total = 0;

                switch ( elem.getNodeName() ) {
                    case "current":
                        current = Integer.parseInt(elem.getTextContent());
                        break;
                    case "total":
                        total = Integer.parseInt(elem.getTextContent());
                        break;
                }

                if(current < total) {
                    Element element = (Element) elem;
                    element.getElementsByTagName("current").item(0).setTextContent(Integer.toString(current + 10));
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem with this code is, that it throws a NullPointerException at `element.getElementsByTagName(...`. I already printed out the values of the variables `current` and `total` and they were showing the right values, but as I compared it at `if(current < total)`, it was always true, and not false for user1 and for user2 true.

In the end, it should look like this:

```
<config>
    <users>
        <user1>
            <name>test1</name>
            <stats>
                <total>50</total>
                <current>50</current> <!-- Is already the same the value of total, don't edit -->
            </stats>
        </user1>
        <user2>
            <name>test2</name>
            <stats>
                <total>50</total>
                <current>30</current> <!-- Not the same, add 10 to former value -->
            </stats>
        </user2>
    </users>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the comparison of current and total is inside the loop where you populate the two variables. so the comparison is done after only one variable was populated. you need to move the `if` outside the loop, and better check that indeed both variables were set to something greater than zero (assuming that this value cannot come as input)

```
        int current = 0;
        int total = 0;
        for ( int x = 0; x < children.getLength(); x++ ) {
            Node elem = children.item(x);

            switch ( elem.getNodeName() ) {
                case "current":
                    current = Integer.parseInt(elem.getTextContent());
                    break;
                case "total":
                    total = Integer.parseInt(elem.getTextContent());
                    break;
            }

        }
        if(current > 0 && total > 0 && current < total) {
            Element element = (Element) elem;
            element.getElementsByTagName("current").item(0).setTextContent(Integer.toString(current + 10));
        }
```